# Database connection error l while connecting to Database at that time of Installing Informatica 10.4.1

Tags: sql-server, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I just wanted to enquire on an Issue, I faced during the installation of Informatica Server in my PC.
At the time of Installing the server I had to connect to Database, and in that process, I had to connect with a database named : 'infa1' but I am unable to connect to it, I have attached the Screenshots below, Hope you could help me in that matter.

[image: informatica Database Configuration]

In the above fig, I have issue while testing the connection. It is failing, also not sure what is the meaning of Database Address!!!

I even have the Database ready for connection.

[image: database pic]

Also yes the TCP/IP connection is enabled and password entered is also correct

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt in the SQL Server's logs? If so, what is the error presented there for the connection? If not, is `DANNY-PC` the name of the local host? Have you tried replacing `DANNY-PC` with `localhost` if so? If not, can you connect to the SQL Server from the remote host you are setting Informatica on via a different application, such as sqlcmd or SSMS?

Comment: `database addresss` is hostname. for your case it may be localhost. better use the `jdbc connection string` option. its straightforward.

Comment: @KoushikRoy thank you for the info. I tried 'jdbc connection string' also but it did not do any help.

Comment: @Larnu I did not check the LOGS I will do that once and will update that here, also DANNY-PC is not the name of the local host I even tried with "localhost" instead of "DANNY-PC" but still it didn't work.

Comment: can you pls tell us how you put the jdbc string?

Comment: `jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1433;ServiceName=try0`  <-- this is the string. I have changed the database name as `try0`,earlier it was `nfa1` as mentioned in the picture